# Why do viruses cause different symptoms?

Tags: human-biology, immunology, virology, immune-system, tissue

If the sole purpose of a virus is to hijack the nucleus of a cell to replicate, why do we have different symptoms for different viruses?

I can think of the following coming into play:

1. immune response of the body
2. destroying tissue of type A is different than destroying tissue of type B
3. the rate of the destruction --- some (virus, cell) combination are causing more harm than others

Reference:

1. [Why Do Viruses Cause Different Symptoms In Different People?](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2017/04/07/why-do-viruses-cause-different-symptoms-in-different-people/#76fea75b2213) --- talks about how we can have different symptoms for the same virus.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Although we accept medically-related questions, you will see from the [Tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) that we prefer them to be about "the biological mechanisms behind medical conditions". As your question concerns the whole organism, I feel that it would be a better fit for [Medical Sciences Stack Exchange](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score -1):

every virus having differ differ spike proteins so they make infection  a particular type of cell ( just like HIV that only bind with CD4 type of receptor) and make effect. another fact is that every virus have different genomic marital so that have different codon and these different codon make different protein and that different proteins make different effect on host cell metabolism that's why different virus having different symptoms. 
[image: a virus structure]

Comment: Welcome. This doesn't seem to target the question. Rather, your answer looks like a textbook description of the general makeup of a virus.